# Which is better between big range scan with coprocessor vs. multi range scans

Tags: hbase

For example here is an HBase table storing people's info, and each row represents a person, and here are two possible row key schema and columns to consider:

- Plan A: `City+Career+PersonID` and not column
- Plan B: `City+PersonID` and a column named `Career`

Now I want to query people that `city` locates at Asia and `career` is interested,

If the count of city locates at Asia is `N` and the count of careers we interested is `M`, so:

- In Plan A, I will have `N * M` ranges to can.
- In Plan B, I will have `N` ranges to scan, each of the ranges may be big, but I can use a **coprocessor** to do filter.

so the count of scans of Plan A is more than Plan B.

When `M` is small, Plan B has to scan less big ranges and filter out a lot of rows, and maybe Plan A is better.
But when `M` is large, Plan A has to create a lot of scans, which may deteriorate performance, and Plan B maybe better.

If `M` is unknown in advance, how to determine which plan to use?

Comment: Is that an offline use case, or online?

Comment: An offline use case @shay__

Comment: Then I would do it outside of HBase altogether. Create a snapshot and use Spark/MR to process the data directly from the HFiles using the snapshot.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstand the "offline", here I want a ad hoc query actually. @shay__